# Label Propagation Algorithm Implementation in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

[image]I have a set of nodes IP addresses which are connected to each other by :connected_to and I want to implement the label propagation algorithm on them. But after running below command there is no result

```
CALL algo.labelPropagation('Node','connected_to','OUTGOING'(write:true,partitionProperty:'community',weightProperty:'count'))
```

can anyone help me please?[image]

Comment: Do you have a small sample of your graph? Maybe via https://console.neo4j.org

Comment: Hi there, I have attached two snapshots of the source and destination nodes above

Comment: I would recommend you use the GDS library as the graph algo library is already deprecated

Answer (score 0):

## Use the GDS Library if you can.

#### 1. Create the named graph.

If you *really* only have `:Node` labels, you might want to work on that. (:Device?, :Gateway?, etc.)

```
CALL gds.graph.create('projection', '*', '*')
// CALL gds.graph.create('projection', ['Device','Gateway','Node'], 'connected_to')
YIELD graphName, nodeCount, relationshipCount;
```

#### 2. Run the projection

```
CALL gds.labelPropagation.stream('projection')
YIELD nodeId, communityId AS Community
RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).ip AS IP, Community
ORDER BY Community, IP
```

#### 3. Mutate your graph if you want.

```
CALL gds.labelPropagation.stream('projection')
YIELD nodeId, communityId AS Community
WITH gds.util.asNode(nodeId).ip AS IP, Community
MATCH (x:Node {ip: IP})
SET x.community = Community
RETURN Community, count(DISTINCT x)
```

***Sources:***

- https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/label-propagation/
- https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/graph-catalog-ops/
- https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/native-projection/#native-projection

Comment: Thanks Tony for the prompt and complete response, is there any possible way to write the community value to the nodes as well?

Comment: Yes. See step 3 in my answer, "Mutate your graph if you want." There are a variety of ways to do this, just remember to ***not*** use the internal `id(x)`, instead using any node property which is unique. This gets into graph design, so, TL;DR: `UNIQUE` constraints, and `INDEX`, help a lot here. Because you know `node.ip` is unique, you can just use that to `MATCH (x:Node {ip: ip})`